# BlackBerry app whose icon disappears from App Switcher but still is running?

Tags: java, blackberry

How can I make a BlackBerry app have an icon but when a user does something within the app the app will disappear from the app switcher but be running in the background? I'm thinking of a timer app that will do that. Then when the timer is up it will reappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have your application run in two contexts, one a UiApplication context with an icon, one with an Application context without an icon. The Applicatin may be autostarting, or may be started by your UiApplication. This can be done by specifying an alternate entry point into your application.

You have to be very careful with your coding though. Applications that don't exit and are badly written can have a huge impact on performance, battery life and data usage.